# jquery dynamic select append options expecting alert("text")

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic, append, xataface

I have pulled data from backend using Ajax/JSON, and I am trying to append this data to the select box using jQuery. Data is appended to the select box properly, but it is showing on the page only when I put `alert("some text")`.

here is the code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "the_url.php"
    success: function(data) {
        var comp_select = jQuery("select[class='xf-depselect-selector depselect-fragment']").get(3);
        alert("Ready Now");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            jQuery(comp_select).append(jQuery('<option>', {
                value: data[i]["component_name"]
            }).text(data[i]["component_name"]));
        }
    },
    complete: function() {},
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in [document-ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler? It seems your code executing before DOM is loaded.

Comment: yes, the whole thing is in bodyonload(); function.

Comment: Show that code also. Seems issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Satpal, thanks for the response, how can i put my code in this comment.